# Get and edit a file name

Tags: vba, excel, directory

I'm looking to retreive a txt file and then edit the file name (adding **"converted"** to the file name) and extension (from **.r01** to **.txt**). 
The purpose for this is so I can know if the txt file has been converted

Here's my code so far;

---

`Dim infilename As Variant`

> `infilename = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text & r01 Files (*.r01;*.txt),*.r01;*.txt", , "Open Neutral File", "OPEN")`

Comment: you are very unclear. It's difficult to tell what you are asking. Do you want to rename a file?

Comment: I want to get any existing text file(using the 'Open File' prompt), then edit the directory. That's it.

Comment: any existing text file in a directory? and edit what? The file name or directory name? where is the new name coming from? we are not mind readers

Comment: For a file **sample.txt** with directory **C:\Users\Robert\Documents\sample.txt**, I want to simply remove the **.txt** part. I will be adding additional text (**CONVERTED.txt**) to it later in the code. When I do this however I end up with **sample.txtCONVERTED.txt**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I was looking for using part of Sean Cheshire's code.

```
   Dim newFileName As Variant
   newFileName = Left(inFileName, (InStrRev(inFileName, ".") - 1)) & "CONVERTED.txt"
```

Answer (score 2):

`InStrRev` will allow you to find the last `.` and remove it and everything following from the string

```
FileNameWithoutExt = Left(Filename, InStrRev(Filename, ".") - 1)
```

---

An example with the workbooks FullName:

```
?activeworkbook.FullName
```

> Z:\Individual Folders\Sean\transfers2.xlsx

```
?Left(activeworkbook.FullName, InStrRev(activeworkbook.FullName, ".") - 1)
```

> Z:\Individual Folders\Sean\transfers2

---

You can wrap these in a function to make them easier to use. I've also added a function that will give the filename only instead of the one with the full path

```
Function FileNameOnly(fName)
'Changes "C:\Path\Filename.ext" to "Filename.ext"
FileNameOnly=mid(fName,instrrev(fName,"\")+1)
End Function

Function DelExt(fName)
'Changes "C:\Path\Filename.ext" to "C:\Path\Filename"
DelExt=left(fName,instrrev(fName,".")-1)
End Function
```

You can then use these in your program, with a line like `NewFileName=DelExt(infilename) & "CONVERTED.txt"`

Comment: If I wanted to remove everything after the last `.` then would that work too?

Comment: It doesn't work. My file is under the variable _infilename_. I put the variable name in place of _Filename_, ran the code and nothing happened differently

Comment: note there are 2 places to put your `filename` variable. look at the example I have added

Comment: I don't think this works. When I use the code and add the **CONVERTED.txt** it won't let me save the file,

Comment: added example on how to use the code as a function, so it can be included in your preogram

Comment: I've just included the second function and there's no difference. It does change the file name but it can't be saved with the new changes.

Comment: then I would look at the filesystem to ensure it can save the file with the name you desire

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33990/discussion-between-robert-english-and-sean-cheshire)

Comment: I fixed my stack error and everything looks nice and tidy. There's no more errors popping up but what I go to click the SAVE button for the new file, nothing happens. I can keep clicking but still nothing. I'm forced to Cancel each time.